# How to generate a column with the difference between TimeStamp

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
    df_Valve = pd.DataFrame({'TimeStamp':['2018-01-01 00:00:00', '2018-01-01 00:00:05',
                                          '2018-01-01 00:00:07', '2018-01-02 00:00:07', 
                                          '2018-01-02 00:00:08'], 
                             'Sensor_Temp': [53, 66, 69, 69, 69],
                             'Sensor_StrainGauge': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]})

    df_Valve


           TimeStamp           Sensor_Temp    Sensor_StrainGauge 
    2018-01-01 00:00:00           53                0
    2018-01-01 00:00:05           66                0
    2018-01-01 00:00:07           69                0
    2018-01-02 00:00:07           69                1
    2018-01-02 00:00:08           69                1
```

I need to add a new column in the dataframe. This new column should contain the difference between the 'TimeStamp' of position 0 and the 'TimeStamp' of position 1 (row 1). Then the difference between the 'TimeStamp' of position 1 and the 'TimeStamp' of position 2 (line 2) and so on.

The desired output is:

```
          TimeStamp           Sensor_Temp    Sensor_StrainGauge      New_Columns
    2018-01-01 00:00:00       53                0                   0 days 00:00:05           
    2018-01-01 00:00:05       66                0                   0 days 00:00:02
    2018-01-01 00:00:07       69                0                   1 days 00:00:00
    2018-01-02 00:00:07       69                1                   0 days 00:00:01
    2018-01-02 00:00:08       69                1                   0 days 00:00:00   #last index
```

I implemented the following code (but it is not correct):

```
    for i in range(0, len(df_Valve)):
        for j in range(1, len(df_Valve)):

            #difference between timestamp position 0 and 1, 1 and 2, 2 and 3 ...
            df_Valve['New_Columns'] = abs(pd.to_datetime(df_Valve['TimeStamp'].iloc[i]) - 
                                         (pd.to_datetime(df_Valve['TimeStamp'].iloc[j])))
```

The output of my algorithm is incorrect and is shown below:

```
         TimeStamp           Sensor_Temp    Sensor_StrainGauge      New_Columns
    2018-01-01 00:00:00       53                0              0 days            
    2018-01-01 00:00:05       66                0              0 days 
    2018-01-01 00:00:07       69                0              0 days 
    2018-01-02 00:00:07       69                1              0 days 
    2018-01-02 00:00:08       69                1              0 days
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) 
to convert to datetime,then you can use [Series.diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) with [Series.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) 
to get the differences as you want them,finally [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) has been used to 
fill in the last value:

```
df_Valve['TimeStamp']=pd.to_datetime(df_Valve['TimeStamp'])
df_Valve['New_Columns']=df_Valve['TimeStamp'].diff().shift(-1).fillna(pd.Timedelta(0))
print(df_Valve)
```

---

```
            TimeStamp  Sensor_Temp  Sensor_StrainGauge     New_Columns
0 2018-01-01 00:00:00           53                   0 0 days 00:00:05
1 2018-01-01 00:00:05           66                   0 0 days 00:00:02
2 2018-01-01 00:00:07           69                   0 1 days 00:00:00
3 2018-01-02 00:00:07           69                   1 0 days 00:00:01
4 2018-01-02 00:00:08           69                   1 0 days 00:00:00
```

Comment: This line: df_Valve['NewColumn'] = df_Valve['TimeStamp'].diff().ffill()

Generates the following error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Yes, perfect. Tks